# Pagination using PHP and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, pagination

I have a following sql query which works fine for paging

```
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ClientID) 
            AS rowID, Status, FirstName, LastName FROM Client)
        AS TEMP
        WHERE (rowID BETWEEN ? AND ? + 1)";
```

When I add one more condition (Status != -1) in where clause, it doesn't show me the same number of rows on every page.

```
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ClientID) 
            AS rowID, Status, FirstName, LastName FROM Client)
        AS TEMP
        WHERE (rowID BETWEEN ? AND ? + 1) AND (Status != -1)";
```

Please does anyone knows how to write this query to get same number of rows on each page. Thanks

Comment: use your additional were conditions in the sub query `FROM Client WHERE Status != -1`

Comment: You need to add the condition (Status != -1) in your inner select query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the condition (Status != -1) in your inner select query.Try this below script,

```
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ClientID) 
                AS rowID, Status, FirstName, LastName FROM Client
            WHERE (Status != -1) )
        AS TEMP
        WHERE (rowID BETWEEN ? AND ? + 1) 
        ORDER BY rowID";
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much, that was too easy.

Comment: Now where can I add ORDER BY clause pls

Comment: You can use 'ORDER BY rowID' in the last part of your query. Answer modified plz chk.